# dynamically set smart gwt list grid header

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I have created a smartgwt [list grid](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#setFields%28com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGridField...%29). The grid headers are static and the content is filled with server side data. 
The code looks something like this

```
ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
grid.setFields();//set columns names..  
grid.setData();//pass datasource..
```

On page load, it first initialize the grid object, set field names (columns) and when the server side data is available, it populates the grid.

This approach is fine when the columns/headers are static. However, I am trying to modifying the grid so that headers are set dynamically. To be more specific, server data will include information about grid header (number of columns of the grid, column names etc). One way to do this, put the header information in a grid content cell and design that cell to look like header.

I want to know if there is any better approach to do this ?

Comment: can't your differ the creation of the listgrid to match the server response event ?

Comment: If you don't know in advance the fields you'll need, I'd agree with @Jean-MichelGarcia. Create new ListGrid when data is fetch.  If you know all the fields which can be brought back by server, then create all fields and play with `setHidden(true/false)`.

Answer (score 0):

did you see this:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_top_header

Comment: but this is adding the header in the SectionStackSection and not the LitGrid itself. this will not help if you have multiple list grids and you want to have a header/title for each one seperately